# How to stop Interval?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, oop, methods

I'm trying to create a button that will stop a method running a setInterval.

I'm using clearInterval to do so, but it won't let me target the setInterval variable for some reason.

```
class Helpers {
    static start(value: Vehicle): void {
        let begin = setInterval(value.calculateSpeed, 1000, value);
    }
    static stop() {
        let stop = clearInterval(Helpers.begin);
    }
}
```

I also tried with namespace instead but didn't work either.

```
namespace Extras {
    export function start(value:Vehicle) {
        let begin = setInterval(value.calculateSpeed, 1000, value);
    }
    export function stop() {
        let stop = clearInterval(Extras.begin);
    }
}
```

the start() method runs fine...but the stop() method doesn't do anything. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you very much for your help guys! You solved my problem!

Comment: `Helpers.begin` is `undefined` because `begin` is a local variable.

Comment: let is scoped to the function, not the class or instance. I would expect something like `Helpers.begin = setInterval()`, but then written in typescript syntax ( if it differs ).

Comment: Why would you need these dummy classes? Just use `setInterval` where it belongs in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the referenced variable to be static. Currently, the variable `begin` is local to your `start` function. Also, you don't need to keep a reference of the value returned by `clearInterval`. A better name for `begin` would be `interval` or `intervalId`

```
class Helpers {
    static interval;
    static start(value: Vehicle): void {
        Helpers.interval = setInterval(value.calculateSpeed, 1000, value);
    }
    static stop() {
        clearInterval(Helpers.interval);
    }
}
```

Update:
However, making the `intervelId` static is not a good idea, since you might want to use this Helper class at more than one place simultaneously. Making it static will create a single copy of the variable which can lead to problems.

A better approach would be something like this:

```
class Helpers {
    private _intervalId;
    start(value: Vehicle): void {
        this._intervalId = setInterval(value.calculateSpeed, 1000, value);
    }
    stop() {
        clearInterval(this._intervalId);
    }
}
```

And to call the function you may use some objects:

```
const helper:Helpers = new Helpers();
helper.start();
```

Also, make sure that `helper.start();` is not called more than once before it is stopped with the same object. To handle this edge case properly you can check the value of `_intervalId` in `start()` and throw some error if it is already set. In case of `stop()` you can set `this._intervalId = null`

Comment: This is disgusting, why do you make everything static when there is no reason to?? Just use `this.interval`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Helpers {
    private _intervalRef;   

    start(): void {
        this._intervalRef = setInterval(function () { console.log('hello') }, 1000);
    }
    stop() {
        clearInterval(this._intervalRef);
    }
}

const helper:Helpers = new Helpers();

helper.start();

helper.stop();
```

You can create same with above code reference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your `begin` interval static too:

```
class Helpers {
    static begin;

    static start(value: Vehicle): void {
        Helpers.begin= setInterval(value.calculateSpeed, 1000, value);
    }

    static stop() {
        clearInterval(Helpers.begin);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `begin` and and `stop` as you class property and then do the same you are doing now!

Answer (score 0):

`begin` is a local variable. Declare it outside start as below,

```
class Helpers {

    static begin;
    static start(value: Vehicle): void {
        begin = setInterval(value.calculateSpeed, 1000, value);
    }
    static stop() {
        let stop = clearInterval(Helpers.begin);
    }
}
```